# Fedora doesn't boot, black screen after grub

Tags: fedora, boot, grub, uefi

I have a Fedora 31 and Windows 10 dual boot.

Everything was working great for months before I updated my Windows 10. Now my Fedora 31 does not boot. It's just blank screen after grub and I cannot even boot a Fedora 31 live USB, and I get the same black screen after grub.

Switching to 3rd run level doesn't work, emergency mode doesn't work, turning off Nvidia drivers doesn't work, updating UEFI doesn't work, and disabling Fast Boot and Secure Boot doesn't work.

Also, probably not related, my HD Audio controller driver completely doesn't work in Windows.

The worst thing is that a live USB doesn't work as well. Booting Fedora with a live USB has the same issue after grub.

I have tried everything I could find on this and other forums.

Here is a screenshot of what grubs spits out when trying to boot (that was shown when I added a special param in "e".

[image]

At the bottom says of the screenshot it says: `kernel panic not syncing attempted to kill idle task`

I need Linux for college, and currently I cannot even boot into it.

Notes:

- When I turn on CSM (Compatibility mode in UEFI, at least the Fedora logo shows up after grub, not just black screen).
- I didn't try switching UEFI to Legacy, because that would mean I'd risk losing my files.
- Motherboard ASUS ROG B360-F

Comment: I strongly suspect UEFI  BIOS Utility has to do something with this issue.

Comment: Does booting into a previous kernel work?  How about if you add “acpi=off” to the kernel parameters?

Comment: Booting into previous kernels or rescue doesn’t work. The output you see on the screenshots is with acpi=off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Turns out one of my ram cards was faulty. I removed the bad ram card and things began working as expected.